# Is this a japanese cedar?

Tags: identification, bonsai

I've been growing this tree (as a bonsai) for quite a while and for a long time I thought it was a Japanese Cedar. But now I'm not so sure.

Can anyone tell me what kind of plant this is?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is actually a *Juniper procumbens* 'nana'.